# Copy file from Azure ADLS G2 to Azure Data warehouse without staging

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am having issue try to Copy file from Azure ADLS G2 to Azure Data warehouse without staging using polybase.

ErrorCode=FailedDbOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Please make sure SQL DW has access to ADLS Gen2 account,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=External file access failed due to internal error: 'Error occurred while accessing HDFS: Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_IsDirExist. Java exception message: HdfsBridge::isDirExist - Unexpected error encountered checking whether directory exists or not: AbfsRestOperationException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, HEAD, [https://xxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/production//?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90',Source=.Net](https://xxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/production//?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90%27,Source=.Net) SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=105019,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=105019,State=1,Message=External file access failed due to internal error: 'Error occurred while accessing HDFS: Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_IsDirExist. Java exception message: HdfsBridge::isDirExist - Unexpected error encountered checking whether directory exists or not: AbfsRestOperationException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, HEAD, https://xxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/dev//?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90',},],'

The adf have contributor right and have read write access to the ADLS.

Please advice!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

1.turn on `Allow Azure services and resources to access this workspace` in Azure Data warehouse.

[image]

2.assign Storage Blob Data Contributor to your Azure Data warehouse.

[image]